# Inject Context to activity

Tags: java, android

I am combining a static code analysis with a dynamic one. I basically create a new activity and set it up as the starting activity. During the run various methods in existing activities should be called.

I can call e.g. `onCreate` from outside, however, the super call to `Activity` will fail (or  calls to SharedPreferences or other interesting classes) since Android does some initialization stuff when using the intents in order to call an activity (e.g. setting the context). But I need to somehow call methods like `onCreate` or `onPause` from outside while giving the target activity a valid context.

In my newly created activity I have got a valid context. I tried to pass it via calling `ContextWrapper.attachBaseContext`, but there is still a `NullPointerException` somewhere in Android due a the missing context. Is there some way to hack this somehow into a working state? Using reflection or other hacks would be no problem, since it is for analysis purposes only.

Thank you very much for any tips. I'd be able to modify the analyzed apps in any way to get this working.

However: Using an Intent is no option, since I cannot control which Activity-methods are being called, when and how often. I know that android has not been made for calling these methods directly, but it is not a common use case either :);

Answer (score 0):

I have created a hack, which seems to help (I can get a valid context in the hacked activity). Let's see how far I get using this.
        public static void hack(Activity hack, Activity main) {
       try {
           Field mActivityInfo = getField(Activity.class, "mActivityInfo");
           mActivityInfo.set(hack, getClass("android.content.pm.ActivityInfo").newInstance());
           Field mFragments = getField(Activity.class, "mFragments");
           Field mContainer = getField(Activity.class, "mContainer");
           Field mApplication = getField(Activity.class, "mApplication");
           Field mWindow = getField(Activity.class, "mWindow");
           Class FragmentManagerImpl = getClass("android.app.FragmentManagerImpl");
           FragmentManager manager = (FragmentManager) mFragments.get(hack);

```
       mApplication.set(hack, main.getApplication());
       mWindow.set(hack, main.getWindow());

       Class<?> FragmentContainer = getClass("android.app.FragmentContainer");
       Method attachActivity = getMethod(FragmentManagerImpl, "attachActivity", Activity.class, FragmentContainer, Fragment.class);
       attachActivity.invoke(manager, hack, mContainer.get(hack), null);


       Method attachBaseContext = getMethod(ContextWrapper.class, "attachBaseContext", Context.class);
       attachBaseContext.invoke(hack, new HackContext(main));
       System.out.println("Hack performed");
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.err.println("Hack failed :(");
   }
```

}